# Conditional Join Statement in MySQL using IF-ELSE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a notification scheme for my social networking app. I've different kind of notification which are categorized in two groups: Friends-related and Events-related. Currently, my database schema is like this:

```
+---------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| notification_id     | int(11)                | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| notification_type   | enum('event','friend') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_date   | datetime               | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_viewed | bit(1)                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id             | int(11)                | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now, I've two different tables fro event-related notification and friend-related notification. Below is schema for event-related notification table:

```
+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type                                               | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| notification_id         | int(11)                                            | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| event_id                | int(11)                                            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| event_notification_type | enum('added','kicked','new-message','info-edited') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And again I've 4 more tables for each `kicked`, `added`, `new-message`, `info-edited` type of notification, since each requires to have it different kind of property (for example `kicked` requires a reason).

Now, I want to write a conditional SQL query such that it joins the `notification` with `event_notification` if `notification_type` is `event` otherwise different.

SELECT * FROM notification_table t WHERE t.seen = FALSE AND  t.user_id = ? INNER JOIN event_notification en ON(t.notification_type='event' AND en.notification_id = t.notification_id) INNER JOIN .....

There is going to be so many inner joins is there any better way of doing it? I think my query is not very optimized either, would appreciate if any help could be provided.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?  You are proposing joins with all of the other tables but only returning the columns from `notification_table`.

Comment: It would still be easier to have one table for the notifications.  Just because one of the notifications requires a reason doesn't mean the other types couldn't also use that table and have that reason field be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the joins.  However, you want to create the query using left outer joins rather than inner joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM notification_table t
WHERE t.seen = FALSE AND t.user_id = ? left JOIN
      event_notification en
      ON(t.notification_type='event' AND en.notification_id = t.notification_id) left JOIN ...
```

Don't worry about the proliferation of joins.  If your tables have proper indexing, they will perform fine.

Do consider changing the data structure so you have only one table for the different notification types.  Having a few fields that are not used does not add much performance overhead, especially when you consider the complications of having so many joins and the additional management overhead of having more tables.

Comment: Thanks. Very good answer. What kind of data structure would you suggest? Should I at-least have two two tables or just one?